# Can I make an ethernet sniffer with Android NDK?

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk

I tried at making a `socket` with an Android NDK wrapper, passing the file descriptor to Java to be used with a `recv` wrapper. The target user should not require Single User. The `recv` call does not receive any data. Why?

TCP sockets can not be read without a connection, because they require sequentiality. UDP packets were not being received either. RAW sockets were, of course, not being successfully made. My code had more bugs than a restaurant's dumpster, I was calling `shutdown` instead of `close`... not sure why. It's April fools, and usually I delete questions once I realize I'm being an idiot and wasting people's time; but today I have a bounty on this question, so I think I'll revisit this idea for a bit and post better code. Check back later if you're still interested.

Comment: Why aren't you using Java sockets?

Comment: If I were you I'd add some native-side logging of the value of sd and also perhaps add some code or use run-as to check the status of that socket in /proc/net  Also don't forget that thhings like the network on the main thread rule and Internet permission will still apply in JNI.

Comment: Probably not what you are worrying about right now, but you are using the length of a *jint* array as a *size_t* (or a count of *bytes*), which will likely result in only using a quarter of your array.

Comment: Did you ever bind() your socket to an address and listen() for a connection, or else connect() to an external server?  If not, this seems like expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Android doesn't support reading from unconnected sockets.

*TCP* doesn't support reading from unconnected sockets, or writing to them either. Your socket is of type `SOCK_STREAM,` and you are calling `shutdown()` on it, so it must be a TCP socket.

NB:

1. `shutdown()` doesn't close the FD. You must also call `close().`
2. `recv()` returning -1 doesn't necessarily mean 'socket closed'. You need to look at the value of `errno` to decide what it does mean.
3. Your title 'Java Native Socket Not Persistent' has nothing to do with your question.